# exponential bound on the number of possible clusters at $0$ in $\mathbb{Z}^d$

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

Let us say that $\mathbb{Z}^d$ is given the usual lattice structure as a graph.  I want to know the number of connected induced subgraphs of size $k>0$ that include the vertex $0$.  Call this number $a_{dk}$.  For example, $a_{22}=4$.

If $a_{dk}$ has no closed formula, then I wish to at least show that for all $d\ge1$ there exists $C>0$ such that for all $k>0$ we have $a_{dk} \le C^k$.  So I am wishing for an exponential bound in $k$.

In $2$ dimensions, one can use what is essentially a variation of the Peierls argument for phase transition/percolation critical parameter to show that this is the case, by converting the question of enumerating the connected subgraphs to the equivalent question of enumerating contours.  But this isn't valid for any other dimension, and it isn't even valid in $2$ dimensions because it is not the case that every connected subgraph is bounded by a single contour.  But that is my work on this problem, and I am also interested in a discussion of if there is a generalization of the Peierls argument along the lines of discussion of this problem to $d>2$. (For instance, if your answer ends up enumerating the boundaries in higher dimensions, perhaps that means that the Peierls argument could be generalized.  But I am not hopeful, as this would be a very big advancement for probability theory.)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Peierls argument works/can be made to work on lattices $\mathbb Z^d$ of every dimension $d\geqslant2$. For a gentle recent introduction in the framework of the Ising model, see [The Peierls argument for higher dimensional Ising models](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.7894) by Claudio Bonati.

As in Peierls' original work, this yields no closed formula but loose exponential upper bounds.